# Logback: Is it possible to combine the TimeBasedRollingPolicy with a SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy?

Tags: logging, logback, rollingfileappender

I use Logback with a `TimeBasedRollingPolicy` that rolls the files once an hour:

```
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <fileNamePattern>${serverpath}/logs/history-debug/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
    <maxHistory>168</maxHistory> <!--7Days-->
    <totalSizeCap>2GB</totalSizeCap>
</rollingPolicy>
```

Sometimes the original (not yet rolled) log files can grow very large in my case (several GB). I now would like to add a `SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy` to the configuration to additionally roll the file when the original log file exceeds a certain limit (5GB for example). 
So the log files should be rolled over once an hour except if the file gets to big, then it should be rolled over earlier.

I tried this one:

```
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <fileNamePattern>${serverpath}/logs/history-debug/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
    <maxHistory>168</maxHistory> <!--7Days-->
    <totalSizeCap>2GB</totalSizeCap>
</rollingPolicy>
<triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
    <maxFileSize>5GB</maxFileSize>
</triggeringPolicy>
```

But then I get an error as the `%i` is incompatible with the TimeBasedRollingPolicy.

I also tried the `SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy` but that one only chunks the rolled over files into smaller parts but does not look at the original log file's size.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to combine the TimeBasedRollingPolicy with a SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy?

Yes, `SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy` is the solution for you.

```
<appender name="APPLICATION" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>D:/logs/log.txt</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>%p %d [%t] %L - %m%n</Pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>D:/logs/log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm}.%i.txt</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
        <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>20GB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```

> configuration to additionally roll the file when the original log file exceeds a certain limit (5GB for example)

here is the size limit for you: `<maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>` change it to 5GB, I have tested it with 1MB, but it will work for any size

> So the log files should be rolled over once an hour except if the file gets to big, then it should be rolled over earlier.

If I understood you correctly you want to roll based on a max size or time, whichever is reached first. The time based rolling is achieved through this: `{yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm}`. This one rolls every minute, if you want to roll every hour, use: `{yyyy-MM-dd HH}`.

The above appender, when used, gives this output:

[image]

You can see that files are rotating at a max size of 1MB if this size reaches within a minute, or if the size doesn't reach but the time reaches it rolls still (that is evident in files `log.2019-01-04 12-23.2.txt` and `log.2019-01-04 12-24.3.txt`)

The logback.xml which should work for you is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>
    <!-- Send debug messages to System.out -->
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%p %d [%t] %L - %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="APPLICATION" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>D:/logs/log.txt</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%p %d [%t] %L - %m%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>D:/logs/log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH}.%i.txt</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>5GB</maxFileSize>
            <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
<!--            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>20MB</totalSizeCap>-->
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="javaportreader" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="application" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="APPLICATION"/>
    </logger>

    <!-- By default, the level of the root level is set to DEBUG -->
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="APPLICATION"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```